# No continuar después de llamar a driver.get() en Python Selenium

Tags: python

Tengo un problema al intentar ejecutar el driver.get ya que se queda ahí y no continúa con la ejecución del código. Adicional si lo hago con execute_script para abrir una nueva pestaña, tampoco funciona el driver no me detecta esta nueva pestaña.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.ie.service import Service as IEService

ie_options = webdriver.IeOptions()
ie_options.ignore_protected_mode_settings = True

dirIE=r"C:\\Assets\\IEDriverServer.exe"
ie_service = IEService(executable_path=dirIE)
driver = webdriver.Ie(service=ie_service, options=ie_options)

url = "https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/inputs"
print("Aqui Va 1")
driver.get(url)
print("Aqui Va 2")
```

Comment: si te abre el navegador?, marca error o simplemente no abre?, ya intentaste con el driver de chrome?

Comment: Si me abre el navegador, solo se queda alli, en el driver.get sin continuar en el codigo, y si abro otra pagina con execute_script tampoco me detecta la otra nueva pagina o pestaña, lo requiere abrir en egde en modo internet explorer ya que el aplicativo que quiero automatizar no funciona en otro navegador.